# Multiplicative structure on solution space of a linear PDE

Tags: ring-theory, partial-differential-equations

Given a differential operator, $L$, on $\mathbb{R}^n$. I want to show that if $L$ satisfies the following properties
$$
Lf = Lg = 0 \implies L(f + g) = 0, \qquad L(fg) = 0
$$
then 
$$
L = \sum_{i = 1}^n c_i \frac{d}{dx^i}, \qquad c_i \in \mathbb{R}
$$
I'm not sure how to rule out that higher order differential operators could have this nice multiplicative structure on the solution space.

Comment: Consider two first-degree polynomials $f$ and $g$. You have $Lf=Lg=L(f+g)=0$ but $L(fg)\neq 0$. They key is that your property must hold for any such functions, so you can pick nice ones.

Comment: @dbx I don't quite understand this counter example. Consider $L = \frac{d^3}{dx^3}$ on $\mathbb{R}^1$. This operator is linear and for $f$ and $g$ first degree polynomials, we have $L(f) = L(g) = L(f + g) = L(fg) = 0$.

Comment: Commenting from a smartphone means incomplete comments, sorry... I had in mind a second order operator. For third order, consider linear times quadratic, etc